# n-stair / step climbing problem: cannot conceptualize why T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I'm having trouble conceptually understanding the solution to the well-known n-stair climbing problem. The n-stair problem is:

You have n-steps to climb. You can only climb 1 or 2 steps at a time. find the number of ways to reach Nth step.

To keep it simple, let's just use the case where `n = 2`. The solution is `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)` and this is of course the Fibonacci sequence.

The explanation as to ***why*** usually goes something like this:

> You are at the nth step. How did you get there given that you could climb 1 step or 2 at a time? Well, your previous step must be at either step `n-1` (took 1 step) or step `n-2` (took 2 steps). Now, there are `T(n-1)` ways to reach the n-1th step, and `T(n-2)` ways to reach n-2th steps, which means that there are `T(n-2)` ways to reach `n` if your last step was at `n-2`, and `T(n-1)` ways to reach `n` if your last step was at `n-1`. Those are the only two possibilities of how you finally reached n, so the total number of ways to get to nth step is `T(n-1) + T(n-2)`

I have trouble conceptualizing the part below:

> there are `T(n-1)` ways to reach the n-1th step, and `T(n-2)` ways to reach n-2th steps, which means that there are `T(n-2)` ways to reach `n` if your last step was at `n-2`, and `T(n-1)` ways to reach `n` if your last step was at `n-1`.

This sounds wrong. The explanation seems to contradict itself.

> there are `T(n-1)` ways to reach the n-1th step

and

> and `T(n-1)` ways to reach `n` if your last step was at `n-1`

And similarly for `T(n-2)`

I also get confused on a second point. When we say that the solution is `T(n-1) + T(n-2)` my brain shouts out 'but wait a minute, you're double-counting. T(n-1) *already* *includes* T(n-2)'.

Can someone help me conceptually understand the reason why `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)`

PS This is not question regarding implementing a solution, but rather a question as to how to explain/understand the answer.

Comment: If you have trouble following a mathematical proof, a programming Q&A site is probably a wrong place to come for help.

Comment: Maybe you should try writing out all the possible sequences for small values of N. Write each sequence as a series of step numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you count some duplicate path in `T(n-1)` and `T(n-2)`. But, the last step to the final is different! So, think like this. The last step could be 1 or 2. Now, from this separation, you will have a different path and you shouldn't worry about anything in the modeling.

Comment: If you worry about anything (and everything?) you should probably see a professional :)

Comment: Thank you! When you said `the last step to the final is different! So, think like this. The last step could be 1 or 2`, that made it clear.You have a set of answers (call them paths, strings, list, whatever) and you add a suffix. To the `T(n-1)` set you can only add `1` and to the `T(n-2)` you can only add `2`

Answer (score 2):

> the reason why `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)`

The post you quote takes (what seems to me to be) the odd step of looking at the *end* of the process.

Let's instead consider what happens when we are at the *start* of the process, at the bottom of a staircase of `n` steps. What can we do *right now*?

- We can take 1 step, which leaves us with the `n-1` problem to solve

OR

- We can take 2 steps, which leaves us with the `n-2` problem to solve.

Clearly, we either do one or the other. So the number of ways of solving the `n` problem is precisely the number of ways of solving the `n-1` problem PLUS the number of ways of solving the `n-2` problem.

Or, `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)`.

Comment: This, plus @OmG's comment helped me understand. The key was for me to see each individual way to climb the stairs as a list, for example 1,2,1,1. At step n, the set of solutions are all the lists from n-2 with a 2 appending, and all the lists from n-1 with a 1 appended.